# Running useradd with shell_exec

Tags: sudo, php, useradd

After trying to give permissions to /etc/passwd, the useradd command wont execute from php's shell_exec();
I also tried to visudo and change passwd's owner, the error is still

```
useradd: Permission denied.
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.
```

How to create bash user accounts with php ?

Comment: I have to ask, but *why* do you want to use PHP, a dynamic language that is fairly easily exploitable, to manage or add users on the system?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with APACHE user permissions.
You can either give sudo permissions to your script which is not the best idea, security-wise.
Or use `ssh2_connect` to connect to your server with ssh and run only useradd as root.

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'root', '')) {
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    ssh2_exec($connection, "useradd $username -m -p $password -d /home/$username/ -s /bin/false");
} else {
    die('Authentication Failed...');
}
```

See [ssh2_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) and [ssh2_auth_password](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-password.php) docs.

Comment: By default, Root is not permitted to login via password.  This is still insecure because you have to permit root logins from everywhere, unless you set it so SSH only listens locally  (which then shields you from brute-forcing attempts).  This however is still insecure.

Comment: I find it more secure than giving permission to the whole script, the best way is to give permissions to a specific user and then local ssh with that user.

Comment: as an IT security guy I agree... to a point.  The actual question is "Why do you want PHP to manage your users", which is its own security concern.